# Can i get a configMap value from an external file?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I have this configMap defined :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
  labels:
    app: my-config
data:
  myConfiguration.json: |
    {
    "configKey": [
        {
          "key" : "value"
        },
        {
          "key" : "value"
        }
    }
```

and this is how i use it in my pod :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: someimage
  name: someimage
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: someimage
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: someimage
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: someimage
          name: someimage
          command:
            - mb
            - --configfile
            - /configFolder/myConfig.json
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2525
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /configFolder
      hostname: somehost
      restartPolicy: Always
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: my-config
            items:
              - key: myConfiguration.json
                path: myConfiguration.json
```

my question is : is it possible to keep the value of the myconfiguration (the json string) in a separate file, separated from the configmap? in order to keep it clean? How would i need to change the deployment and the configmap yaml definitions so i do not have to change the application?

Important : i cannot use any separate templating tool.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can! Using Kustomize.

Kustomize is kubectl sub-command introduced in 1.14, and it has a lot of features that will help customize your deployments.

To do that you'll have to use `ConfigMaps Generators`. This will require an additional file `kustomization.yml`.

So if your deployment yaml file is `deployment.yaml` and your configMap's name is `my-config`, then the `kustomization.yaml` should look something like this

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - deployment.yaml
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config
  files:
  - myConfiguration.json
  - myConfiguration2.json # you can use multiple files
```

To run kustomize you'll have to use `kubectl apply` with the `-k` option.

Edit: Kustomize will append the value of the hash of you ConfigMaps into their names. Having that it will be able to track changes on you configurations and trigger a redeploy for you whenever they change.

So no need for deleting your pods whenever you configMaps are altered.